# Rearranging a logarithmic equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

I'm building a web app that displays the frequency of a sound. I have an equation that returns a pixel that a particular frequency should be mapped at. However I would like to reverse the equation so that it returns the frequency that a specific pixel relates to. I haven't really worked with logarithms much before and so I am having difficulty with it.

The pixel to frequency equation is:

$$    p = \frac{\frac{\log f}{\log 10} - \min }{r\cdot w}. $$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: is it OK to partially answer the OP's question in your edit?  The original post was $\log{f}/\log{10}$.

Comment: yeah that edit confused me a bit as to why it became log10(ƒ)

Comment: I changed the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\log{f}/\log{10} = \log_{10}{f}$.  Then do a little algebra to write your equation as

$$\log_{10}{f} = r \, w \, p + \text{min}$$

which implies that

$$f = 10^{r\, w\, p + \text{min}}$$

In psuedocode:

```
x = r * w * p + min;
f = 10^x ;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It helped a lot although strangely the equation that worked for me in the end was `f = 10 ^ p*(r/w)+min`. I'm not sure why though.